Analyzing Range of Features for Classification
I have developed a classifier with 5 ordinal classes, and I’m looking to do a detailed analysis on the range of values required for each class (1 through 5).
For example, I want to understand how a feature like column A (with a value range of 5-10) combined with other features, influences the model’s prediction of it as a certain class.
While we’ve been using SHAP for feature importance analysis, we need to dig deeper given that we’re working with app activity data. Specifically, we need to determine the thresholds or amount of each feature needed to transition from one class to another (e.g., 5 more likes for a certain content will transition a user from class 1 to class 2, or class 2 to class 3).
Our primary goal is to gain actionable insights that would allow us to move users from a lower class to a higher one (e.g., from class 1 to class 4). This information will help us make improvements to our app or marketing strategies.
EDIT: I am using a TabNet Classifier

This also depends on the type of model you're using, which you haven't specified, for a regression model you could simply look at all the splitting criteria. A method to look into would be counterfactual explanations, for example on this page of the DiCE package.

Hi @Oxbowerce, edited the question.  I am using a TabNet classifier then I treated the problem as a normal multiclass classification (ordinal encoded labels).

Like I said, look into the research on counterfactual explanations as a model agnostic tool to help explain what changes would lead to a different prediction by your model.

Thank you. will read about this and as to how I can apply it to multiclass problem.

You are essentially trying to find the decision boundaries for the 5 outcomes of your ML model. Lets say you have n features, the boundaries will be n-dimensional polygons. As the amount of features increases this gets complex really fast, so you'll have to approximate.
Tabnet uses feature masks in the decision process which are stored in a variable  feature_selection_masks (Pytorch tabnet). Have a look at which features get selected the most and those are the ones you could manipulate/evaluate to find the insights in your model you are looking for.
